# Oracle 12c database NOLOGGING

Tags: database, oracle, recovery

Our database is Oracle 12c and we have some temporary tables created with NOLOGGING option.

My concern is in case of database recovery can we recover those tables(i'm interested only for the DDL structure of course,  no data) ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a table or index as `NOLOGGING`, the database does not generate redo log records for the operation. Thus, you cannot recover objects created with `NOLOGGING`, even if you are running in `ARCHIVELOG` mode, only a small set of metadata is written to the redo logs.

Please check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-42825ED1-C4C5-449B-870F-D2C8627CBF86.htm#VLDBG1578) where it gives the process on how to retrieve the data when `nologging` mode is set to on.

Comment: OK, but let's say i have the following scenario. 1.create table with no logging 2.next day backup database. Can i recover table structure in the interval after backup ?

Comment: When you create a table/index with `nologging` in clause will send the actual create statement to the redo logs (this information is needed in the data dictionary), but all rows loaded into the table during the operation are **NOT** sent to the redo logs. So you can get the information of the table structure from there.However please note that You must take a backup, both before and after all `nologging` operations